# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'move_uploaded_file' (T_STRING) en php al insertar una imagen en una base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, imagen

Estoy creando un blog, me base en un video, primero hice un formulario en donde voy a recoger datos para guardarlos en una base de datos y luego mostrarlos en otra interfaz, el error que tengo presente es al momento de insertar una imagen, me dice unexpected move_uploaled_file, este es el codigo amigos

```
<?php

 $host ="localhost";
 $usuario = "root";
 $clave = "";
 $bd = "seguridad";

  $conexion = mysqli_connect($host,$usuario,$clave,$bd);

   if ($_FILES['imagen'] ['error'] ) {
      switch ($_FILES ['imagen'] ['error'] ) {
        case 1 :
        echo "El envio del archivo se a interrumpido";
        break;
        case 2 :
        echo "No se envio el archivo debido a una lenta conexión";
        break;
                                      }

     } else {
      echo "No hay error en la trasnferencia de archivo";
     if ( (isset ($_FILES ['imagen'] ['name']) && ($_FILES ['ímagen'] ['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OR) ) {
        $destino_de_ruta="imagenes/"

//LINEA 25 move_uploaded_file($_FILES ['imagen'] ['tmp_name'], $destino_de_ruta . $_FILES ['imagen'] 
       ['name']);
           echo "el archivo se a copiado en el directorio de imagenes";



    }else{
          echo "el archivo no se a copiado";

          }

      }


     $titulo = $_POST['campo_titulo'];
     $fecha = date ("y-m-d");
     $descripcion = $_POST['area_descripcion'];
     $imagen =$_FILES ['imagen'] ['name'];

    mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO contenido (Titulo, Fecha, Descripcion, Imagen) values 
    ('$titulo', '$fecha', '$descripcion', '$imagen')");
     echo "Se agrego tu publicación con exito";


 ?>
```

Comment: puedes mostrar el formulario?

Comment: Identifique te te falta un " ; " al final de `$destino_de_ruta="imagenes/"`

Comment: Amigo le puse un punto y coma y me vota el error syntax error unexpected ;